# how to make a comment post api in django related to the single blogpost detail?

Tags: python, django, api, comments, django-serializer

I have a page where a blog post detail is displayed. Under the post, there is a section where user can comment after inputing thier name subject and text in a comment box. Now i have to make an api for this. I want to make a post api such that that comment is stored/associated to that particular blogpost detail. That means i need blogpost id to pass while posting comment. How to do that??

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('travel_news', 'Travel News',),
        ('travel_tips', 'Travel Tips',),
        ('things_to_do', 'Things to Do',),
        ('places_to_go', 'Places to Go'),
    )
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='travel_news')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
   
    # todo support for tags
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='#travel') #todo
    date_created = models.DateField()

    @property
    def html_stripped(self):
       from django.utils.html import strip_tags
       return strip_tags(self.content)
         
    @property
    def comments(self):
        return self.comments_set.all()
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class CommentPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'subject', 'comment',]



class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentListSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['image', 'categories', 'description', 'content', 'tags', 'date_created', 'comments']
        # fields = '__all__'
```

Here is my view:

```
class CommentCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentPostSerializer
```

Comment: *"That means i need blogpost id to pass while posting comment"* ... Pass the relevant data as post payload.

Comment: Apart from that, `APIView` class doesn't have any effect on putting  `queryset` or `serializer_class` attributes

Comment: Sorry, its CreateAPIView in my code. I did a mistake while posting here. I have edited here. Can you please check it. Ok, now what should I add to my serializers/view so that my particular comment is associated to that blogpost only not others?? I am quite new. Can you walk me through??